# Destroy session by visiting another page - php

Tags: php, session

I want to destroy one session on different page. So basically when I redirect visitor to (for example "success.php") the session will be destroyed no matter on time left.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["log"])) {
  $from_date = $_SESSION["log"];
  $minute = 30 - round(abs($date - $from_date) / 60,2);
  $ips = explode("/", $ip_sessions);
  if(in_array($ip, $ips) && $minute > 0 && $minute < 30) {
    $valid = true;
  } else {
    session_destroy();
  }
```

so I just want to have another page "success.php" with other content, but visit of this page will destroy the session from above that is on "index.php".

Can anyone help me to write the code to destroy this session on new page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session_destroy();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Is this all that you need or am I totaly misunderstanding your question here?

Comment: Well I cannot just add session_destroy on new page where it doesnt contain defined session that is supposed to be destroyed.

I dont know how to write full code on new page that will destroy previous session (code from above)

Comment: Did you include session_start() before the session_destroy() on the new page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may also be able to use `unset($mySession)` to destroy a particular variable.